# how to handle the grid [Tk]

Tags: grid, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I created a grid that contains five labels
each label in a row
but I want in each row has the same size of previous label least size of one colone

**code  :**

```
label .f0 -text "frame 0"\
    -relief groove \
    -borderwidth 2 \
    -background blue
label .f1 -text "frame 1" \
    -relief groove \
    -borderwidth 2 \
    -background gray
label .f2 -text "frame 2" \
    -relief groove \
    -borderwidth 2 \
    -background green
label .f3 -text "frame 3" \
    -relief groove \
    -borderwidth 2 \
    -background yellow
label .f4  -text "frame 4"\
    -relief groove \
    -borderwidth 2 \
    -background red

grid .f0 -row 1 -column 1 -sticky ewns
grid .f1 -row 2 -column 2 -sticky ewns
grid .f2 -row 3 -column 3 -sticky ewns
grid .f3 -row 4 -column 4 -sticky ew
grid .f4 -row 5 -column 5 -sticky ew
```

**printScr :**

[image]

So my question is how I can filling the space that the arrow indicates with Grid not pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -columnspan option to grid to specify how many columns to use:

```
  grid .f0 -row 1 -column 1 -sticky ewns -columnspan 5
```

References: [grid](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm)

**Edit:**

```
foreach i {0 1 2 3 4} {
  grid columnconfigure . $i -weight 1 -uniform labcol
  grid .f$i -column $i -sticky ew -columnspan [expr {5-$i}]
}
```

This is similar to Peter's setting of minsize.  It makes all the
columns the same width.

Comment: it's correctly work (I change `-sticky w` to `-sticky ew`)

Comment: The layout engine gives each widget a box consisting of one or more rows and one or more columns. The `-sticky` option says how the widget handles the space in the box when there is more than it needs.

Answer (score 1):

(*2nd try*) Add this after your code as in the question:

```
foreach index {1 2 3 4 5} {
    grid columnconfigure . $index -minsize [winfo width .f0]
}

grid configure .f0 -columnspan 5
grid configure .f1 -columnspan 4
grid configure .f2 -columnspan 3
grid configure .f3 -columnspan 2
```

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [winfo](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/winfo.htm)

Comment: @AnsPiter: if you need to show code in reply to an answer, put it in your question instead: that makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: sorry but can you add the full code and explain the role of `configure` because I have some confusion between it and `columnconfigure`

Comment: @AnsPiter: is it really necessary to copy all your code over here? Just paste my code at the end of your code. It worked for me, so it should work for you. The difference between `grid configure` and `grid columnconfigure` is that `grid configure` changes options for how the slaves are managed by the grid, while `grid columnconfigure` changes options for the grid itself (specifically, for the *index*th column). You can do the same kind of configuration with `grid configure` as you did when you originally added slaves to the grid with the `grid` command.

Comment: Ugh, can't resist... "you want the grid? **You can't handle the grid!**" (And I know it doesn't quite match the actual quote.)